# Assembly Will not load from Mapped Drive

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an application that uses a handful of home brewed assemblies that builds and runs fine in VS2015 and when files are copied locally.

When I copy the folder structure from release to a server location, and run the exe from the Mapped drive path (H:/) it fails to find one of my DLL files. If I use the UNC path it loads fine. I have tried using fuslog (Assembly Binding Log) but it doesn't give me any useful information.

If there is any other information you need to help me troubleshoot, then ask away.

Thanks!

**NOTES:**

Using .NET 4.5.2

I did deploy as "Release"

Other Assemblies load fine and are noted as "operation successful" in fuslog.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/12/30/using-caspol-to-fully-trust-a-share/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was unable to find anything in the post that helped. I was able to work around the problem by utilizing a third party utility (Costura Fody) to bind the DLL with the EXE. Still open to suggestions on why this issue was happening in the first place.